# Encrypted number code problem; guide is "ex2^3^2"

Tags: cipher

I got this strange encoded message;

**576 512 64 1408 320 1216 1280 960 768 320 896 1600 960 1344 1152 192 960 960 704 576 320 1216**

With this guide:

[image: number]

What does it say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a fairly trivial encoding:

> Divide all the numbers by 64 and apply A1Z26, and you get:
>  **I HAVE STOLEN YOUR COOKIES**
>
>  Not sure what the $2^{3^2}$ means, as that gives $2^9=512$ which isn't 64.

Comment: Znlor BC zrnag $(2^{3})^{2}$

Comment: @Auribouros yes, I think you're right.